# Can't get upload image value by using React hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to build a form that can upload multiple images.
 The images can be removed during the preview images.

For example, I upload the two images then, I try to click the remove button to remove one of two images that are working fine.

The problem is during I click the submit button suppose will post one image to API but there are still remaining two images post to API.
 I'm using the React hook form, anyone knows what is the problems?
Here is the project links
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hermann-xrqbt

```
const methods = useFormContext();
const { control, watch, setValue, formState } = methods;
const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

function deleteFile(id) {
  const s = image.filter((item, index) => item.id !== id);
  setImage(s);
}

<div className="flex justify-center sm:justify-start flex-wrap -mx-16">
  <Controller
    name="images"
    control={control}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <label
        htmlFor="button-file"
        className={clsx(
          classes.productImageUpload,
          "flex items-center justify-center relative w-128 h-128 rounded-16 mx-12 mb-24 overflow-hidden cursor-pointer shadow hover:shadow-lg"
        )}
      >
        <input
          accept="image/*"
          className="hidden"
          id="button-file"
          type="file"
          onChange={async (e) => {
            function readFileAsync() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const file = e.target.files[0];
                if (!file) {
                  return;
                }
                const reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = () => {
                  resolve({
                    id: FuseUtils.generateGUID(),
                    url: `data:${file.type};base64,${btoa(reader.result)}`,
                    type: "image",
                  });
                };

                reader.onerror = reject;

                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
              });
            }

            const newImage = await readFileAsync();

            setImage([newImage, ...image]);
            onChange([newImage, ...image]);
          }}
        />
        <Icon fontSize="large" color="action">
          cloud_upload
        </Icon>
      </label>
    )}
  />
  <Controller
    name="featuredImageId"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) =>
      image.map((media) => (
        <div
          onClick={() => onChange(media.id)}
          onKeyDown={() => onChange(media.id)}
          role="button"
          tabIndex={0}
          className={clsx(
            classes.productImageItem,
            "flex items-center justify-center relative w-128 h-128 rounded-16 mx-12 mb-24 overflow-hidden cursor-pointer outline-none shadow hover:shadow-lg",
            media.id === value && "featured"
          )}
          key={media.id}
        >
          <Icon
            className={classes.productImageFeaturedStar}
            onClick={() => deleteFile(media.id)}
          >
            Delete
          </Icon>
          <img
            className="max-w-none w-auto h-full"
            src={media.url}
            alt="product"
          />
        </div>
      ))
    }
  />
</div>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Edit still-sea-ijvrk]

---

You can't programmatically set the value of an input with `type="file"` for security reasons.

```
<input
  ...
  type="file"
  onChange={uploadimg}
  // remove the value prop
/>
```

In the `readFileAsync` function, you need to account for the multiple files that will come, so instead we pass one `File` to it.

You were concatenating the result of the `FileReader` to get a valid `Base64` string, but you can just use [`FileReader#readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). And that function will return the `Base64` string for the image.

```
function readFileAsync(file) {
  ...
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve({
        id: uuid(),
        url: reader.result,
        type: "image",
      });
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

And in the `uploadimg` function,

```
async function uploadimg(e) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    setImage([...images, (await readFileAsync(file))]);
    setFiles([...files, file]);
  }
}
```

In the `deleteFiles` function, now we have to update the `image` and `files` states.

Because in the `files` state, the images aren't recorded by anything unique, So we use the insert position `(from the uploadimg function)` to match the files and remove the one to delete.

```
function deleteFile(id) {
  const imageIndex = images.findIndex(item => item.id === id);

  if (imageIndex > -1) {
    setImages(images.filter(item => item.id !== id));
    setFiles(files.filter((_, i) => i !== imageIndex));
  }
}
```

}

---

###### For the saving

There isn't a need for for the `react-hook-form` package, since the input with `type="file"`'s value cannot be set programmatically.

So if it's the files from the input you want to access

- you can use a `ref` to access it
- store the file in another state
- use the `Base64` strings you generated.

I used another state to hold the files in the [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-breeze-f7gov?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), but you can use any of the three options.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and solution. but when i click the save button still can't get the values

Comment: @sy523. Check the edit

Comment: The results is no problem.  But I need  use react hook form to do it because  the upload is one field of the form , another field all use react hook form methods .

Comment: Okay then @sy523. But you shouldn't use the value the `Controller` provides on the file input, it won't do anything. Just store the Files in another state or use another method I spoke about to get the file value.

Comment: Sorry to inform you. i just found that your solution was used input file multiple . Actually want select image one by one  not select multiple images in one time.

Comment: @sy523. You can check the edit. Hope it'll do this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237194/discussion-between-sy523-and-a-mola).

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  this is not my expected results because i need use getValues() method in react hook form for get the images value.

Comment: @sy523; I’ll use the  `setValue` function provided from the `react-hook-form` to set the `image files`. And then you should be able to get the images using `getValues`

Comment: ok now  should be working https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hermann-xrqbt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: now I setValue ( "images", files) in the save button function . But in my project the save button  in another component  how can i pass the files state value to the save button function.

Comment: @sy523; Check the chat